# Filtering on objects.all() isn't behaving lazy in Django

Tags: django, performance, filter, django-queryset, lazy-evaluation

Django querysets are supposed to be lazy but it seams as though the following is not.

I have the following (5 seconds) slow code (on 200,000 records):
1. `qs = MyCars.objects.all()`
2. 
3. `qs = qs.filter( car_id__gt=0 )`

The following filtering is fast:
A. `qs = MyCars.objects.filter( car_id__gt=0 )`

What am I missing? (And for reasons I must include line 1).

To make it more interesting. If I on line 2 add:
2. `qs2 = qs`
And then on line 7:
7. `qs2 = qs2.filter( car_id__gt=0 )`
Then it is fast. 
So, I thought I'll use qs2 to filter on line 3 but then it is slow.

Comment: They should all be instant, because you haven't done anything with the `qs` so they are not evaludated. Are you showing all the code you have?

Comment: I have about 8000 lines of code but the the lines involved are accounted for above. I do print('--') between each line and I see where the hold up is.

Comment: There's definitely something else that hurts the performance. An apparent way for verification is django shell. If you run your queries in django shell I bet they return instantly.

Comment: Also, it's very unlikely that all your code is working on `qs` you got from the query, so I could suggest you editing your question to show the relevant work. It might be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Please don't change what I wrote becuase it is intended to be written exactly as I wrote it. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I had written `if qs:` on line 2. I changed it to `if qs.count() > 0:`. I didn't realize I had missed an importan portion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your aren't performing any of the operations mentioned [here in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) as they will cause the queryset to be evaluated and it will run a query on the database.

If you are causing the queryset to be evaluated it will take longer if the filter at that moment is very general and causes large amounts of data to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause is when you are inspecting the variables. In my case, I was using PyCharm debugging, and it was evaluating the queries, i.e. executing them, while I was inspecting them.